# Ruby hook for method defined?

Tags: ruby

I've been googling around for this and haven't been able to find an answer, which makes me think the answer is no, but I figured I'd ask here in case anyone knows for sure.

Does Ruby have a hook for when methods are defined (ie on a module or class)?

If not, is anyone familiar enough with the implementation of the `main` object to know how exactly it copies methods to `Object` when they're defined at the top level?

Really curious about this. Thanks for any info :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It does. `Module#method_added` https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Module.html#method-i-method_added

```
module Thing
  def self.method_added(method_name)
    puts "Thing added #{method_name}"
  end
  def self.a_class_method; end
  def do_something; end
end

class Person
  def self.method_added(method_name)
    puts "I added #{method_name}"
  end
  attr_accessor :name 
end

Thing
Person.new 

# Thing added do_something
# I added name
# I added name=
```

Comment: My hero! Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0):

> If not, is anyone familiar enough with the implementation of the `main` object to know how exactly it copies methods to `Object` when they're defined at the top level?

It doesn't "copy methods". The language specification simply says that methods defined at the top-level become methods of `Object`. This is exactly the same mechanism as the one that says that methods defined inside `class Foo` become methods of `class Foo`. The language spec says it, therefore the implementors implement it that way. `main` doesn't need to do anything.

If you want to get *real* technical, then this is about [the *default definee*](http://blog.yugui.jp/entry/846), which is the implicit scope in which methods get defined when you don't explicitly specify the definee (as in `def foo.bar; end`). *Usually*, the default definee is the `self` of the closest lexically enclosing class or module definition body, and when there is no lexically enclosing class or module definition, it is `Object`. But some reflective methods, such as `instance_eval` or `class_eval` etc. *may* or may not change it.