# How can I call a method at the end of every subclass declaration from a superclass?

Tags: ruby, inheritance

**Edit** - *Changed question to clarify what I need and remove any confusion*

I have a superclass with a class method that needs to be called in every subclass:

```
class SuperClass
   def self.super_method
     puts "super method was called"
   end
end
```

I need this method to be called at the end of every subclass (after all methods are defined):

```
class SubClassA < SuperClass
  def some_method
    puts "some method was called"
  end
  super_method
end

class SubClassB < SuperClass
  def some_other_method
    puts "some method was called"
  end
  super_method
end
```

However, I don't want to manually call super_method at the end of every subclass, like in the example above. Instead I want to find some way to automatically call this function at the end of every subclass from the superclass, something that works similarly to the inherited method

```
class SuperClass
   def self.super_method
     puts "super method was called"
   end

   self.inherited(subclass)
     subclass.super_method
   end 
end
```

The reason inherited won't work is because inherited is fired as soon as a subclass inherits from the superclass (on the line 'class SubClassA < SuperClass") but I need the method to be triggered after the subclasses methods (some_method, and some_other_method in this case) have been defined. I'm hoping there is some sort of build in method like the inherited method that could do this.

```
class SuperClass
   def self.super_method
     puts "super method was called"
   end

   self.methods_loaded(subclass) #not a real built in method, but hopefully something like this exists
     subclass.super_method
   end 
end
```

If no such method is built in to ruby, then how can I simulate this functionality?

**Old Question**

***NOTE - I'm leaving part of the old question in. If you know the swift protocol/delegate pattern I think this next part will help clarify exactly what I need and why. If you don't then feel free to ignore the of this question.***

I'm working on creating custom classes in ruby to add a pattern similar to the protocol/delegate pattern in Swift. I am pretty much done and as it stands the following code does everything I need it to:

```
class SampleProtocol < Protocol
  required_method :number_of_sections_in
  required_method :number_of_rows_in_section
end

class SampleClass < SwiftClass
  inherit_protocols :SampleProtocol
  def number_of_sections_in; end
  verify_conforms_to_protocols
end
```

I won't go in to too much detail about how it works, since that is not the problem right now, but basically SwiftClass contains the two method calls above; inherit_protocols and verify_conforms_to_protocols. If I were to run the code above, it would raise a custom Method Missing error because Sample Class doesn't contain the required method: number_of_rows_in_section defined in SampleProtocol. The error is raised in the verify_conforms_to_protocols method.

So basically, all of that logic works. The problem I have now is that I don't like having to call verify_conforms_to_protocols at the end of every class that inherits a protocol. Instead I'm looking for a way to have every single subclass of SwiftClass call that method **after** all of the other internal set up code for the subclass is run (ie: it must be called after all the methods are defined, otherwise the classes will never conform to the protocols.)

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I'm not completely following because I'm not familiar with the pattern (or Swift) but it sounds like using `prepend` might do what you're expecting... http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-prepend

Comment: Yeah the pattern isn’t super important just the fact that I need  the method verify_conforms_to_protocol to be called after all other methods are declared in the subclass, but I don’t want to manually put it at the end of every subclass. I’ll look into prepend when I’m back on my computer and see if it works.

Comment: One way you could do it is implementing a `self.method_added(name)` method that compares the currently defined method to the list of defined methods from `self.methods(false)` or `self.instance_methods(false)`. More info on `method_added` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48352057/ruby-hook-for-method-defined/48352154#48352154

Comment: @JoshBrody I edited the question so hopefully it's a little bit more clear what I need now. As for the method_added and prepend neither will work. method_added won't work because the super method needs to be called after all of the methods are defined, not as each one is added. And from what I understand after reading on prepend it's intended for modules and I'm dealing with classes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how you could do what you want to do without resorting to something that's been whooped real good with an ugly stick, like the following.

```
class SuperClass
  self.singleton_class.send(:attr_accessor, :last_subclass)

  def self.super_method
    puts "super method was called from #{self}"
  end

  def self.inherited(subclass)
    last_subclass.send(:super_method) unless last_subclass.nil?
    self.last_subclass = subclass
  end 
end

class SubClassA < SuperClass
  def some_method
    puts "some method was called"
  end
end

class SubClassB < SuperClass
end
  #super method was called from SubClassA

class SubClassC < SuperClass
end
  #super method was called from SubClassB

class SubClassDummy < SuperClass
end
  #super method was called from SubClassC
```

Note that if you run this from IRB you will need to quit and restart IRB each time you run it.